# Center DIV vertically and horizontally with border, padding and margin

Tags: html, css

I need to center a DIV horizontally and vertically:

```css
div.wrap {
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
 div.main {
 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the `main` DIV to have a border, padding and margin.

When I decrease the height of the browser window the Botton border goes over the text.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't understand... you are saying you need for the `main` div to have border, padding, and margin, in your CSS rules, the main div already has that.... Also, the border-bottom doesn't go over the text like you are saying....

Comment: I just mentioned padding and margin because I want to keep applying both. If you decrease the height of the window enough you will see the Botton border over the text

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% get what you're trying to do but maybe a different solution to your problem while still retaining the height/width:

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace margin with a transparent border and then rely on `margin:auto` to center

```css
div.wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  inset:0;
}
 div.main {
  border:20px solid transparent;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px inset red;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```